# angles::normalize_angle_positive not resolved

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use the function angles::normalize_angle_positive in a callback function. Unfortunately I constantly recieve the message 'could not be resolved'. I can't find this function in this namespace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49763/angles::normalize_angle_positive-not-resolved/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you include  angles in the manifest?

Other than that: Copy the exact error and code + commands where this error happens. Do no retype anything.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2012-12-06**:
Hi. Thanks for your answer. Nope I didn't include it in the manifest. I thought i was part of the ros package (I am quite new to ros). I included it and included the correct heade "angles/angels.h" and now it works. Thanks for you hint!

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2015-04-17**:
There is a typo: `angles/angles.h`. Thanks anyway!